# python3 change the index encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python3. I have pandas dataframe object named temp, the column names of which are encoded by 'gbk'. I would like to decode the column names and rename the columns, however the temp.columns will give me a index object:

```
temp.columns
```

The result is:

> Index([b'IF00', b'SH000300', b'date', b'\xbb\xf9\xb2\xee'], dtype='object')

How can I can I rename the columns with the decoded list of strings?

Comment: does `temp.columns.str.decode('utf-8')` work? or whatever encoding you desire

Comment: This gives an error message: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Sorry you have to cast to a `Series` first I get this: `In [265]:

df.columns.to_series().str.decode('utf-16')
Out[265]:
b'IF00'                  䙉〰
b'SH000300'            䡓〰㌰〰
b'date'                  慤整
b'\xbb\xf9\xb2\xee'      僚
dtype: object`